# php regex to find all names

Tags: php, regex

I am using below regex to find all names start with class and end with .inc

```
    ^(class)?([^\s]+(\.(?i)(inc)))$
```

But it's not working.
It's showing all the names but I only want to select names start with class and end with .inc
Any help please

Comment: *But it's not working* What does this mean? Do you get any errors? Does your computer explode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possibility of getting unwanted result may be due to `?` which marks `(class)` group as *optional*. Try this:

```
^(class)([^\s]+(\.(?i)(inc)))$
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cG5xM3/1)

Comment: I am getting below error by omitting ?
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'RegexIterator::__construct() [<a href='0regexiterator.construct0'>regexiterator.construct0</a>]: Unknown modifier '\''                              ( ! ) InvalidArgumentException: RegexIterator::__construct() [<a href='0regexiterator.construct0'>regexiterator.construct0</a>]:

Comment: not sure how did you use it ? but here you can see it is working on php live tester: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/cfa

Comment: Thanks...I am using RegexIterator..something like 
$files = new RegexIterator($ite, '^class.*inc$', RegexIterator::GET_MATCH);   where $ite is a RecursiveIteratorIterator

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^class.*inc$
```

Tested with: class_test.inc